# How to display vs 2010 code analysis warning in the current active file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We are using visual studio code analysis in our current project. With time we have accumulated quite a lot of warnings.

What we would like to do is to clean the warnings on the go instead of threating them all of them in a huge batch.

So is there a way to display the code analysis warnings for any current active file ? The same way it's done for compile errors  with the little blue "wiggle" thingy ?

Or is there any plugin/tool ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that ReSharper can help in that :

> Code quality analysis
>   On-the-fly code quality analysis in C#, VB.NET, XAML, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, JavaScript, CSS, HTML, and XML. ReSharper will tell you right away if your code contains errors or can be improved.

[List of features](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, wish I could have a 'free' solution ;)